# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I regularly ask for the notification token with:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

yet the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken callback is consistently called on my iOS 8 iPad and never on my iOS 7 iPhone (not even the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError one), not even by deleting the app and reinstalling it: nor the alert is displayed. I checked both the certificates and the settings in my iPhone but all seems in order, as well test all the suggestions in SO and all over the internet but nothing seems to fix it. Any more suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

This can be due to a permission deny. Application uninstall does not reset this permission.

In order to verify whether this permission is denied do the following(**iOS7**):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone;
```

If the permission is denied you will have to do the following steps:

1. Reset permissions in device settings
2. Remove the app
3. Move device clock two days ahead
4. Restart the phone
5. Install application and run again

   - Don't forget to set the clock back after notifications permission popup.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the callbacks are called. For the former you mean setting the notification to nothing? I already removed the app to no avail as well reinstall it. Never tried to move the clock in advance, though. I will try it.

Comment: Nothing to do I followed the procedure in full, but the callbacks keep on not being called.

Comment: I forgot to add a restart step. Please try again. I've updated the procedure

Comment: I made really many restarts, but those callback keep on insisting not to be called on my iOS 7 iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following setting in your Xcode project target:
Target project>Capabilities>Push Notification
Enable the Push Notification and check if you have added the 'Push notification' entitlement to your App Id.

Answer (score 0):

i am  using following 'Code' and its working for me.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: Same as the code I used without it to work on the iOS 7 iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Now I have upgraded to the iPhone 6S and iOS9 and so I cannot test it any longer. At any rate my code has exactly that test, albeit in Swift:
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge , .Sound] , categories:nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Badge , .Alert , .Sound])
        }